# PayPal integration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I want to add PayPal payment system to my RoR app. For this I did install `paypal-sdk-rest` gem.

I have a model `Feed` and inside of index.html.rb, where the route is:

```
get '/:locale/feed', to: 'feed#index', as: 'feed'
```

I want to paste the next code:

```
<%= link_to 'checkout', feed.paypal_url(products_url) %>
```

And inside of the model feed.rb:

```
def paypal_url(return_url) 
values = { 
    :business => 'my_paypal_mail@gmail.com',
        :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_url,
}   
values.merge!({ 
    "amount_1" => unit_price,
    "item_name_1" => name,
    "item_number_1" => id,
    "quantity_1" => '1'
})

     "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
 end
```

But it prints me, that:

```
undefined local variable or method `feed' for #<#<Class:0x007f5644b79520>:0x007f5644b89858>
```

on

```
<%= link_to 'checkout', feed.paypal_url(feeds_url) %>
```

What is the problem and how can I fix this error?

**UPDATE**

I just want to paste button just for payment, to my website with the amount 1$. How can I make it?

Comment: Add feeds_controller and the full content of *index.html.erb* in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Where is feed object defined? If in controller then it should be instance variable like @feed, To access variables defined in controller from views we have to defined them as instance variables like @feed.